# Is there any way to reverse categorical value to original string or text value?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I have applied below is the data frame

```
   cc  temp  
0  US  37.0     
1  CA  12.0     
2  US  35.0     
3  AU  20.0
```

Now convert into category using

```
df =  df.cc.cat.codes
```

I'm getting this as output

```
   cc  temp  
0  2  37.0     
1  1  12.0     
2  2  35.0     
3  0  20.0
```

My requirement is that how can I reverse it as origin any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `LabelEncoder` from `sklearn.preprocessing`, which offers a similar functionality to what you've done.

Here's how to do it with your dataframe:

```
# Assuming you've created the dataframe already

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()

# Transforming categorical variable to label encoded form
df['cc'] = le.fit_transform(df['cc'])

# Converting back from label encoded form to labels
df['cc'] = le.inverse_transform(df['cc'])
```

You can read about label encoder and scikit-learn's implementation at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html.

Might also help to read about other forms of encoding categorical variables such as one hot encoding and target encoding, and which to use where.